# Event Handling Without Subclassing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, appkit

I've recently watched some Lynda tutorials on how to program in Objective C and Cocoa. Coming from a PHP and C# background, one thing caught my attention - event handling. As I was watching the tutorials, the mentor was going through subclassing in order to attach to events.

He eventually discussed creating delegates and attaching to the events that way - better, but still not near as easy as C#. However, I later found out that not everything has a delegate, which makes things even *more* difficult.

I've been searching the Internet for a way to handle events without making a subclass so that I don't end up with this application that has an enormous amount of files, but to no avail.

I'm specifically trying to attach to a mouseLeave or mouseOut event for a NSSlider object so that I can hide a label once it's finished sliding.

Is there some way I can attach to the event without doing any subclassing, or is creating subclass after subclass something that I should just get used to?

Comment: If you just want to do something when you finish moving the slider, just put it in the action method -- it's called when you stop moving the slider (if it's not set to be continuous).

Comment: @rdelmar - I'd like it to be continuous because I have a label that's updated as the slider is moved, and I'd like the label to hide once the mouseUp event is fired.

Comment: Then I think you need to subclass -- what's the problem with that? You just need to override one method, mouseUp.

Comment: Doesn't it get a little messy if you have a lot of events on a lot of different objects?

Comment: It could if you really need to subclass them all, but I think that would usually be unnecessary. Depending on the object, a lot of customizing of the controls can be done via delegates.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways for event-handling.
Like you said, subclassing, is probably the easiest. 
Using delegates is another way. In my opinion often the best.
Another alternative is using blocks.

In my opinion Objective-C is very structured, and I prefer it a lot over C#.

Comment: Thanks - I'll just have to get used to subclassing then.